# How to detect Remote notification in didFinishLaunchingWithOption application method in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, remote-notifications

when app in not in background mode ,inactive mode and app is completely closed. than how to detect is their any notification using application's delegate "didFinishLaunchingWithOption" method. i have searched a lot about it but not get anything. please help .

Thanks

Comment: App is in the suspended state. could not get the data from pushnotification. if the user press (or ) click the notification after we can get the data. using "didRecieveRemoteNotification"

Comment: ok you mean to say if the app is in suspended state , than i can't access the notification data in didfinishlaunchingwithOption method when user click on app icon. ?

Comment: Yes,user click the received notification then will access the notification data.

Comment: completly close mean kill (or) terminate the app right?

Comment: yes sir...............

Comment: no way to get the data when app is killed. To relaunch the app then we get the data. its ways to acheive. no other ways. this all in user hand

Comment: if you feel answer is good. kindly accept the answer.

Comment: ok thanks sir .. thanks for your information and time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below methods is used for notifiaction

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
 UILocalNotification *notification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
   if (notification)
   {


   }
}


 -(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
    NSString *token = [[[[deviceToken description]
                      stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<"withString:@""]
                     stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""]
                    stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @" " withString: @""];
    NSLog(@"Token:%@",token);

}

//app is forground this method will access
 -(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{

}
//need to on teh background fetch option in info plist
//app is background state this below mthod will call while notification receives
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
 {
  NSLog(@"Background mode working%@",userInfo);

  if([userInfo[@"aps"][@"content-available"] intValue]== 1) //it's the silent notification when recive preferences and text messages
  {
  }
 }

//handling interactive notification
   - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(nullable NSString *)identifier forLocalNotification:(nonnull UILocalNotification *)notification completionHandler:(nonnull void (^)())completionHandler {
  }
```

Comment: is this background fetch method allow me to fetch notification data when the app has been closed ? (suspended.)

Comment: your answer is good i will try this on immediate basis.. but i want know is this method give me notification data on app's suspended state..

Comment: In background is possible to get the notification data. background means when press the home button to close the app. suspended state means when double click the home button then swipe app to close  @Harry

Comment: Thanks sir for your information . your answer is good but not explained ..

Comment: Yes, if user click the notification to relaunch. then you get data from "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions"methods. if the user don't click the notification. user click the app to launch the application at time we are not able to get the data.

Comment: but the possible ways is store the push notification messages in server database and use API to get the data while app launch.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOption` method

```
 let launchedFromRemoteNotification = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] != nil
```

Comment: can you give me an example with objective c , and i want access notification completely.

Answer (score 0):

You can get Notification in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOption` in this way :

```
(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{

  NSDictionary *notification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
     if (notification) {
          NSLog(@"app recieved notification from remote%@",notification);
   }else{
        NSLog(@"app did not recieve notification");
   }
}
```

Try this it may help you.

Comment: i try this but not getting notification when i am clicking on app icon after receiving notification..

Comment: @HarrySaggu Instead of clicking on app icon you have to click on notification.

Comment: Why you need notification data on app icon click?

Comment: He want if app icon click then user can get their notification data .. also on notification click..

Comment: I think you can not get notification data on app icon click.

Comment: oh mam,, you are right we can't get data on app icon click.

Answer (score 0):

If the App was terminated and is starting again, you can detect the *Remote Notification* **only if the App is being launched because the user tapped on the remote notification in the notifications tray.**

You can detect it in the *didFinishLaunchingWithOptions* method

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{

  NSDictionary *notificationDict = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
     if (notificationDict) {
        //Your App received a remote notification
   }else{
        //Your App did not receive a remote notification
   }
}
```